# Python pandas, where condition on dataframe before defining the df

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to apply a where condition on the dataframe before defining it?An example:

```
fills_df = pd.Dataframe(api.get_fills()).where(fills_df.orderId==orderId).dropna(subset=['orderId])
```

How I currently write it:

```
fills_df=pd.DataFrame(api.get_fills())
fills_df = fills_df.where(fills_df.orderId==orderId).dropna(subset=['orderId'])
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lambda` with `x` instead variable name of `DataFrame`:

```
fills_df = pd.Dataframe(api.get_fills()).where(lambda x: x.orderId==orderId).dropna(subset=['orderId])
```